# Getting the number of days, weeks and years when the start date and the end date are given in java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm new to Java. What I want is when I pass the start date and the end date to a function as parameters I want to get the number of days, number of months and number of years between the start and the end date.

Comment: have you done any work on this ? Could you please show your code (core logic) you have written till now?

Comment: is this homework? please tag it as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), it's simple:

```
DateTime start = // your start date
DateTime end = // your end date
int days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
int months = Months.monthsBetween(start, end).getMonths();
int years = Years.yearsBetween(start, end).getYears();
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Period.between( 
    LocalDate.of( 2011 , 1 , 1) , 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
).toString();  // Example: P5Y4M2D
```

## java.time

The [Answer by Floyd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835403/642706) is correct but outdated. The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode, with its team advising migration to the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2011 , 1 , 1 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 15 );
```

## `ChronoUnit`

The [`ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) class calculates elapsed time.

```
long elapsedInYears = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( start , stop );
long elapsedInMonths = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( start , stop );
long elapsedInDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop );
```

## `Period`

If you want one span of time broken out as a number of years *and* a number of months *and* a number of days, then use the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period p = Period.between( start , stop );
```

To get the handy standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) formatted String representation, call `toString`. The format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So a month and a half would be `P1M15D`.

```
String output = p.toString();
```

If you want each part as a number, call getter methods.

```
int years = p.getYears();
int months = p.getMonths();
int days = p.getDays();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.